# Angular2 $http promises with Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm triying to implement a simple promise pattern in angular2. The idea is execute a block of code when the two promise get resolved.

The approach is with `Promise.all()` and passing there the promises in my service:

```
predict(data): Promise<any> {
    let headers    = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http
      .post(`${this.baseUrl}/predict`, dataString, headers)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        (res: Response) => Promise.resolve(res.json())
      )
      .catch(
        (err) => Promise.reject(err)
      );
  } // predict
```

And the component controller:

```
promiseOne = this.apiservice.predict(titleToPredict);
promiseTwo = this.apiservice.predict(secondTitleToPredict);

Promise.all(promiseOne, promiseTwo)
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But TypeScript Returns me `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

As i know, the methods are promises, so... i can't figure what is the problem.

Comment: You should omit the unnecessary `Promise.resolve` and `.catch((err) => Promise.reject(err))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be...

```
Promise.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo])
```

... as this method takes one argument - [an Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (such as an Array).